# How to prevent GI pipe from getting corroded

Tags: painting, pipe, primer, corrosion, galvanic-corrosion

I have a hollow GI pipe.

I recently got the top end welded but top end is corroding along with that I think GI pipe is also corroding.

[image]

[image]

I'm think I should unweld the cap and paint the inside of GI by pouring or spray paint and weld a new cap and paint along with exterior of GI pipe.

I feel this would give long life.

Any suggestions on extending the GI pipe life.

I'd appreciate if there are any beautiful decor on the top of post to increase the elegance.

Comment: Did you repaint after welding?  Grind the weld down flat and grind the rust off and repaint.  Ever want a pink flamingos.

Comment: I missed repainting after the welding actually like you mentioned will gride and paint but how about inside of GI , should I spray there or something ? BTW pik flamingos is great day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you weld galvanized (zinc-coated) iron or steel, you burn off the galvanizing in the area near the weld and of course the weld itself isn't galvanized.

So, "unwelding" the top, painting, and rewelding won't do you a *bit* of good.

For the completely over the top approach, you would dismount the whole tube (square isn't pipe) and take it to a hot-dip galvanizing place, which would do what the name suggests (probably after considerable paint removal) and it would be coated inside and out, so long as you don't start welding it more.

Normal people clean up the ugly weld lumps and rust and paint the outside  with cold-galvanizing paint. If you want to paint the inside, remove all the wiring first (paint solvents and wire insulation don't get along well) and use the holes the wiring was in to spray the inside. Practically speaking, it's almost certainly not worth the bother to do that.

If doing it over, make your cap as a slip-fit over the tube that's mechanically joined after galvanizing, not welded on.

Comment: If the OP looks at the rust pattern on the top cap it's pretty clear that the galvanizing has been burn away all around the welded edges, while some remains in the middle.

Comment: you are right , I feel annoyed with the welder who didn't think any of this